# Looking for a programming/development aluminum laptop

Tags: laptop

Specs:

CPU: i7

RAM: 16GB (or configurable) (1600+)

HDD: 512GB SSD (or configurable)

Battery: 8h+

Body: Aluminum

Size: 15"-15.5" display

price: below equivalent Macbook Pro

Comment: These are some generic specifications. What have you found from companies like Dell or HP that don't meet your requirements?

Comment: Sounds like a Gaming Grade laptop to me, sans the GPU. Why not get one with the GPU, so the laptop can be used for rendering as well if need be.

Comment: Look at Acer or Asus. They support these specs and have the aluminum chassis you desire in a laptop. A ROG or a Predator should suffice nicely

Comment: @Andy most of their laptops are plastic and the few that are aluminum either don't have the screen size or the battery capacity.

Comment: @Andy if i had a very specific set of specs, i would just buy that laptop - my options would be limited to 1 or 2. I thought this website is to get recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a big fan of HP these days.. Used to be a big Dell person but they tend to offer less bang for your buck these days.

If your looking to save a few bucks my thoughts would be to scale down the Hard Drive to a 256GB.. That should provide enough space for your core environment. You can always buy cheap external hard drive (or 2nd Internal if possible) later on if it turns out you need to. My set up is to only have core software on the main HD and save projects externally.

Anyways, if that concept is ok with you, then here is one that I've had my eye on..
https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAADF5MK0383

Truthfully, 
You could probably drop the RAM down to 8 GB and still have a pleasurable experience programming. 
https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=1TS-000D-01GH8
This one is configurable, I would take the I7 2.7GHz, non touch, Windows Pro, 256 GB SSD, 8GB RAM.. Thats a pretty good value for $869 and i think HP is doing a pretty good job these days.

One last thought, AMD is making great processors as of late. While their newest line of products hasn't quite hit the market yet (they will be awesome) they still make great products for less then Intel. Apple even released recently that they will be putting AMD in their highest end computers. So, with that said...
Check this one out... This is one that I would buy today if I could. 
http://store.hp.com/us/en/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10151&urlLangId=&catEntryId=1575152&quantity=1
With these options checked...

### Windows 10 Pro 64 - HP recommends Windows 10 Pro. EliteBook 745 G4 with AMD PRO A12-9800B (2.7 GHz, up to 3.6 GHz with Turbo Boost, 2 MB cache, 4 core) + AMD Radeon™ R7 Graphics (Y5Y46AV) ENERGY STAR Qualified Configuration 14" diagonal HD (1366x768) Anti-Glare LED SVA enabled for Webcam slim Integrated HD 720p DualAryMic Webcam 8 GB (1x8GB) DDR4 1866 256 GB PCIe NVMe SSD Dual Point spill-resistant Keyboard No Near Field Communication (No NFC) Intel 7265 802.11 b/g/n/ac 2x2 Non vPro +Bluetooth 4.2 No HP Mobile Broadband No Fingerprint Reader 45 Watt Smart nPFC AC Adapter Power Cord - 1.0 Meters Destination Country Kit Localization 3 Cell 51 WHr Long Life Battery 1/1/0 limited warranty Elite Services Information Card